# SSRS Report run in Chrome isn't using Windows credentials

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Our setup:

1. Server A is where the database lies that holds the report information.
2. Server B is where the report is saved.
3. The report uses a stored procedure that grabs data from the DB on Server A.
4. The report was designed with Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder (15.0.900.71).
5. The report's data source is set to use Windows credentials.
6. Users connect to a database by an AD group (lets call it the "everyone" group) for basic report reading. So even though we haven't created a login/user for each employee on the server/DB, this group should be handling that.
7. For the server, I gave the "everyone" group the public server role and for the user mapping I selected the option for the DB and gave it db_datareader and public roles.
   For the securables I inserted the server name and selected the option for "Connect SQL".
8. For the DB,I gave this group the role db_datareader. I didn't give any securables or extended properties for this user.

I can't think of a time when we had this issue with a previous version of Report Builder (version 10.50.1600.1) and this is the only report that is giving this issue. Chrome keeps giving this error to the end user:

> An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
>
> Cannot create a connection to data source 'SQL01'.
>   (rsErrorOpeningConnection) Login failed for user 'NT
>   AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.

It seems as though when making the report using the new version of Report Builder it isn't correctly passing the user's credentials. Is there something different that needs to be done for this new version of Report Builder or am I doing something wrong elsewhere?

Comment: When the user connects to the report server, are they actually being asked to authenticate? If not, there's your problem. If yes, then Point 5 is wrong, and the report is configured to connect using anonymous credentials. Also, what version of SSRS? Unless I recall incorrectly, Chrome wasn't official supported until SSRS 2016 (it certainly isn't in 2012 and I don't recall it being a feature of 2014; as they was mainly Azure features and the new cardinality estimator).

Comment: @Larnu They are not being asked to authenticate. SSRS version 13.0.4202.2

Comment: Then there's the problem. If they aren't being asked to authenticate then their credentials are never passed. Chrome doesn't automatically pass the credentials of the user; that's only a Internet Explorer/Edge thing. Guessing that due to the report being available to everyone the credentials are never requested, and hence the user is never authenticated. You'll need to either store a set of credentials for the report to use, or ensure that the users authentic before theu view the report; by not making the report available to unauthenticated users.

Comment: I'm a little dubious because we currently have a bunch of reports that users run in Chrome without needing to authenticate. The only 2 things that are different for this situation is the location of the DB/report (the large majority of our reports and their data are stored on Server C while this one report uses Server A/B) and the newer version of Report Builder.

Comment: Then I suspect that those reports are configured with the credentials stored, not to use the credentials of the authenticated user (or in this case, unauthenticated)

Comment: We converted all of our reports to use Windows credentials about a year and a half ago. Could it be that I need to add Server B as a linked server to Server A? I'm not too familiar with how linked servers work.

Comment: I *assumed* that your data source is just pointing to the server it needs to, no?

Comment: Yes, when I go into Report Builder and look at the properties of the data source, it is pointing to Server A with an embedded connection string that uses Windows credentials. However, the server where the report is saved is Server B. This is somewhat new territory for us because normally we have the data and the report all in one server.

Comment: You can create a window user on Server B and setup this account access the Server A if both in a domain. Or use SQL authentication when cross domain will be easier.